# ActiveAdmin : How to avoid duplicating declaration between index and exports?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, dry

I have a rather complicated (having a lot of attributes and methods) model on which I'd like to do a specific view in ActiveAdmin.

I did this for the view, works like a charm.

```
index do 
  column :status
  column "Complex data" do |my_object|
    my_object.compute_complex_data
  end
  [...]
end
```

I'd like to have the same thing in my exports (mainly CSV, but why not XML or JSON). However, by default, I'm going to have my resource exported, and not the column that I see.

One option is of course doing the exact same thing...

```
csv do 
  column :status
  column "Complex data" do |my_object|
    my_object.compute_complex_data
  end
  [...]
end
```

But I'm clearly copy/pasting code, and I don't like this option.

Is there a way to do the same thing while being DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)?

I tried to defined my columns in a lambda without success.

```
common_columns = lambda do 
  column :status [...]
end
csv do 
  common_columns.call
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, DRY is not a law, it is just a recommendation. According to Sandy Metz, for example, "...duplication is far cheaper than the wrong abstraction".

In fact, in these cases you deal with very different views that cannot be the same in principle (for example, web view contains action buttons/links while exports are static). Yes, they could share some of the columns, but is there any good abstraction for this subset? Personally, I don't see any. So I would most probably stay with the explicit definitions - they cause the minimum confusion. But if you still insist...

You can do smth like the following:

```
shared_columns = ->(view) {
  view.column :status
  view.column "Complex data" do |my_object|
    my_object.compute_complex_data
  end
  # ...
}

index do
  shared_columns.call(self)
  actions
end

csv do
  shared_columns.call(self)
end
```

and it should work in general. But again, I think this is an example of blind following a buzzword, this is not a good abstraction so I would most probably avoid such a trick in favor of explicitness.

Comment: I didn't gave you any context about the abstraction I want to do, so I don't see how you can assess whether this abstraction makes sense or not... The only room for discussion I see would be whether such a meaningful abstraction should be done on the admin or elsewhere.

Thanks anyways